# How to fill gaps in floor after wall removal

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

Having recently removed a separating wall between kitchen and kitchen-diner, there is now a gap left in the floor that needs to be filled (150mm x 3000mm).

The floor is ground floor, laid on-top of concrete and is comprised of 25mm thick polystyrene on the bottom, 18mm thick chipboard on top and a layer of plastic sheeting between.

We want to have LVT (Luxury Vinyl Tile) installed like [this](https://www.floorsdirectltd.co.uk/quick-step-light-grey-travertine-livyn-ambient-click-luxury-vinyl-flooring.html).

Here is a picture of the gap:

[image: Gap in floor compromised of polystyrene and chipboard]

**What would be considered best practice in filling this gap to prepare for LVT (Luxury Vinyl Tile)?**

I was thinking to either:

Purchase some sort of ready mixed compound to pour in the gap. If so what sort of compound would be preferable?

or

Fill the gap with polystyrene, chipboard and a layer of plastic sheeting between. If so what to do with the small gaps between the old and new?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question, and well documented. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: what am I looking at in the gap? is that the top of a beam?

Comment: @Jasen it is just ground floor concrete in the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Wood would be best for the here and now and to be gone for later. IF, you'll be removing the existing flooring for the LVT to go in.

Let the LVT installers simply lift out your wood and fill the gap later with Floor Leveler or other cementitious product. It's very difficult to chip stuff away to perfection, but very easy to put it in level with a new permanent elevation.